# Class constructor does not take input parameters C++ (all attributes get the same value and the same value applies to all objects)

Tags: c++, constructor

I created a class named Triangle that takes triangles as objects.

The attributes are the ID of the triangle (m_ID), the index of the three vertices (m_S1, m_S2, m_S3) and the index of the three adjacent triangles (m_T1, m_T2, m_T3).

I want to create a triangle object by passing input parameters in the constructor.

The parameters are passed by value, but the object is badly created. In fact, all three triangles I tried to create (triangle2, 3 and 4) have the same value for attributes. The value is -858993460 which looks like an address.

Even when I use the simplest input values (Triangle triangle4(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)), the attributes are not created correctly.

```
/*
Name: insert
Description: insert the new point and create 3 new triangles
*/
void insert(const int triangleIndex)
{
    // Extract the Index of the new point
    int newPointIndex = pointList.size();

    // Create the line of the second new triangle
    Triangle triangle2(triangleList.size() + 1, newPointIndex, triangleList[triangleIndex].getS3(), triangleList[triangleIndex].getS1(), triangleList[triangleIndex].getT2(), triangleList.size() + 2, triangleIndex);

    // Create the line of the third new triangle
    Triangle triangle3(triangleList.size() + 2, newPointIndex, triangleList[triangleIndex].getS1(), triangleList[triangleIndex].getS2(), triangleList[triangleIndex].getT3(), triangleIndex, triangleList.size() + 1);

    // Test only
    Triangle triangle4(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    // Get the adjacent triangles of the base triangle
    int T1 = triangleList[triangleIndex].getT1();
    int T2 = triangleList[triangleIndex].getT2();
    int T3 = triangleList[triangleIndex].getT3();

    // Update the line of first new triangle
    triangleList[triangleIndex].setS1(newPointIndex);
    triangleList[triangleIndex].setT2(triangleList.size() + 1);
    triangleList[triangleIndex].setT3(triangleList.size() + 2);

    // Update the adjacent triangles
    triangleList[T2].setT3(triangleList.size() + 1);
    triangleList[T3].setT2(triangleList.size() + 2);

    // Insert the new triangles in the triangulation
    triangleList.push_back(triangle2);
    triangleList.push_back(triangle3);
}

/*-----------------------------------------
Name: Triangle
Author: Michael Landry
Description: Implementation of class Triangle
Date: 2018-02-23
Version: 1.00
-------------------------------------------*/

#include "Triangle.h"

// Constructor with no parameter
Triangle::Triangle() : m_ID(0), m_S1(0), m_S2(0), m_S3(0), m_T1(0), m_T2(0), m_T3(0)
{
}

// Constructor with parameters
Triangle::Triangle(int p_ID, int p_S1, int p_S2, int p_S3, int p_T1, int p_T2, int p_T3) : m_ID(p_ID), m_S1(p_S1), m_S2(p_S2), m_S3(p_S3), m_T1(p_T1), m_T2(p_T2), m_T3(p_T3)
{
}

// Global setter
void Triangle::setTriangle(int p_ID, int p_S1, int p_S2, int p_S3, int p_T1, int p_T2, int p_T3)
{
    m_ID = p_ID;
    m_S1 = p_S1;
    m_S2 = p_S2;
    m_S3 = p_S3;
    m_T1 = p_T1;
    m_T2 = p_T2;
    m_T3 = p_T3;
}

// Setter for each individual parameter
void Triangle::setID(int p_ID)
{
    m_ID = p_ID;
}
void Triangle::setS1(int p_S1)
{
    m_S1 = p_S1;
}
void Triangle::setS2(int p_S2)
{
    m_S2 = p_S2;
}
void Triangle::setS3(int p_S3)
{
    m_S3 = p_S3;
}
void Triangle::setT1(int p_T1)
{
    m_T1 = p_T1;
}
void Triangle::setT2(int p_T2)
{
    m_T2 = p_T2;
}
void Triangle::setT3(int p_T3)
{
    m_T3 = p_T3;
}

// Getter for each individual parameter
int Triangle::getID() const
{
    return m_ID;
}
int Triangle::getS1() const
{
    return m_S1;
}
int Triangle::getS2() const
{
    return m_S2;
}
int Triangle::getS3() const
{
    return m_S3;
}
int Triangle::getT1() const
{
    return m_T1;
}
int Triangle::getT2() const
{
    return m_T2;
}
int Triangle::getT3() const
{
    return m_T3;
}


/*-----------------------------------------
Name: Triangle
Author: Michael Landry
Description: Declaration of class Triangle
Date: 2018-02-23
Version: 1.00
-------------------------------------------*/

#ifndef TRIANGLE_H_
#define TRIANGLE_H_

class Triangle
{
public:
    // Constructor with no parameter
    Triangle::Triangle();

    // Constructor with parameters
    Triangle::Triangle(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

    // Setters
    void Triangle::setTriangle(int p_ID, int p_S1, int p_S2, int p_S3, int p_T1, int p_T2, int p_T3);
    void Triangle::setID(int p_ID);
    void Triangle::setS1(int p_S1);
    void Triangle::setS2(int p_S2);
    void Triangle::setS3(int p_S3);
    void Triangle::setT1(int p_T1);
    void Triangle::setT2(int p_T1);
    void Triangle::setT3(int p_T1);

    // Getters
    int Triangle::getID() const;
    int Triangle::getS1() const;
    int Triangle::getS2() const;
    int Triangle::getS3() const;
    int Triangle::getT1() const;
    int Triangle::getT2() const;
    int Triangle::getT3() const;

private:
    // The ID of the triangle
    int m_ID;

    // The 3 vertices forming the triangle
    int m_S1;
    int m_S2;
    int m_S3;

    // The 3 adjacent triangles
    int m_T1;
    int m_T2;
    int m_T3;
};

#endif /* TRIANGLE_H_ */
```

Comment: It looks like that your triangleIndex is having some invalid value (maybe passed array size ...) ...so you are getting some triangle values from triangles that are not initialized ... there is no enough information to tell it for sure ... you can debug and check it

Comment: `Triangle triangle4(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);` worked correctly on my machine, after I cobbled together a Triangle.h.  Maybe there is something in Triangle.h, which wasn't included.

Comment: What ever it is that is wrong, it's not in the code you posted. It really helps to post complete code.

Comment: I thought I posted the .h file the first time. It is now available. The feedback error message I get is that my vector goes out of bounds.

Comment: I found the error. The object triangleList was declared as an object of the class Triangle and not as a vector containing objects of the class Triangle. Therefore, when I tried to access a line of the vector at position triangleIndex, I was searching out of bounds.